# How to play audio when i push a button (like a Xylophone)

Tags: android, button, android-mediaplayer

I am developing an application that should riproduce a sound every time that i press a button, the application is looks like a xylophone, the problem is in the function that plays the sound.

This is the main part of my app:

```
 doo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doo);
  re = (Button) findViewById(R.id.re);
  mi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mi);  
  fa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fa);  
  sol = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sol);  
  la = (Button) findViewById(R.id.la);  
  si = (Button) findViewById(R.id.si);  
  dom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dom);

  doo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v) {
    MediaPlayer sound;
    sound = MediaPlayer.create(Xylophone.this, R.raw.doo);
    sound.start();
   }
  });

  re.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v) {
    MediaPlayer sound;
    sound = MediaPlayer.create(Xylophone.this, R.raw.re);
    sound.start();
   }
  });  

  mi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v) {
    MediaPlayer sound;
    sound = MediaPlayer.create(Xylophone.this, R.raw.mi);
    sound.start();
   }
  }); 

  fa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v) {
    MediaPlayer sound;
    sound = MediaPlayer.create(Xylophone.this, R.raw.fa);
    sound.start();
   }
  }); 

  sol.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View v) {
   MediaPlayer sound;
   sound = MediaPlayer.create(Xylophone.this, R.raw.sol);
   sound.start();
  }
 }); 
  la.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View v) {
   MediaPlayer sound;
   sound = MediaPlayer.create(Xylophone.this, R.raw.la);
   sound.start();
  }
 }); 

  si.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View v) {
   MediaPlayer sound;
   sound = MediaPlayer.create(Xylophone.this, R.raw.si);
   sound.start();

  }
 }); 

  dom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View v) {
   MediaPlayer sound;
   sound = MediaPlayer.create(Xylophone.this, R.raw.dom);
   sound.start();
  }
 });
```

Initially the sound is played without problems, but after a certain number of taps on the screen is no longer any sound, I'm forced to restart the application to make it work again.

Can anyone tell me why ??

**EDIT**

I solve the problem replacing the code with this:

```
doo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v) {
      final MediaPlayer sound;
       sound = MediaPlayer.create(Xylophone.this, R.raw.doo);
       sound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

           public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            sound.release();
           }

       });   
       sound.start();
   }
  });
```

I hope that this edit can help someone :)

Comment: I have another question, is it possible record the sound ?
I would like implements a function that allow the recording of the melody..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new `MediaPlayer` instance to play each sound. MediaPlayers  are resource-intensive and will cause problems when used this way. You should either reuse them or clean them up.

From the [documentation of the `MediaPlayer.create()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) method:

> **When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call release(), to free the
>   resources.** If not released, too many MediaPlayer instances will result
>   in an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written, a new MediaPlayer object is created every time a button is pressed. Over time, your phone will run out of memory.

Try creating 8 sounds after the button definitions and only have 
     dooSound.start();
In the click listeners. 
Check the MediaPlayer documentation to ensure you are handling the object lifecycle correctly.